# What is the difference between ng-click="check=true" and ng-click="alterCheck()"

Tags: angularjs

I use Angular in my project, but I encounter a problem.
When I use `ng-click="check=true"`, after submitting the form, the `div` still shows, not hides as I expected; while using `ng-click="alterCheck()"` or adding `check=true` to the `ng-submit` expression can fix this problem. So what is the potential reason for this problem?

```
<div ng-show="check && form.$invalid"></div>
<!-- <form name="form" ng-submit="check=true && init()"> -->
<form name="form" ng-submit="init()">
    <input type="text" ng-model="text" required/>
    <!--     <input type="submit" ng-click="alterCheck()"/> -->
    <input type="submit" ng-click="check=true"/>
</form>
```

Comment: you wants to hide the div or Form ?

Comment: @gayathri the div of course

Comment: Wait... your `ng-show` condition is `check`, so it is showing when `check` is `true`, what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

hide and chek the conditions

**HTML**

```
<form name="form" >
          <input type="text" ng-model="text" required />
          <input type="submit"  ng-click="do_something()" ng-disabled="form.$invalid"/>
      </form>
   <div ng-hide="!button_clicked && !form.$invalid" >  Invalid Div  </div>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
   $scope.button_clicked = true;
    $scope.do_something = function() {
        alert("Clicked!");
        $scope.button_clicked = false;

    }
});
```

for reference https://plnkr.co/edit/SIi5hVY3v4NO5MRoNwEL?p=preview

Comment: Glad that you answer this problem. I know using a function like `do_something()` can fix this problem. But I am confused that why `ng-click="check=true"` can't fix this problem.